# Start a process in Elisp

Tags: child-process, elisp

How can the following code be made idiomatic in ELisp? Can the temporary `f` variable be removed?

```
(global-set-key [f3] 
  (lambda () (interactive) 
    (let ((f (ffap-file-at-point)))
      (start-process "test" "output" "mpv" f))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the `let`, as you only reference `f` once.

I'd also make it a named function; this makes it easier for you to update the definition, or to bind it to additional keys:

```
(defun start-mpv--file-at-point ()
  (interactive)
  (start-process "test" "output" "mpv" (ffap-file-at-point)))

(global-set-key [f3] 'start-mpv--file-at-point)
```

You might also want to look at the implementation of `shell-command` for inspiration.  Some things it does that might interest you:

- killing any process that's already writing to the output buffer
- erasing the current contents of that buffer
- setting the comint output filter to handle carriage motion
- making the output buffer visible